# Is an equation of the following form solvable?

Tags: exponentiation

Is it possible to solve for $x$ which satisfies the equation $$d=(a\exp(bx)+\exp(cx))x^2$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are given constants? It looks quite horrible... Many thanks!

Comment: Looks doubtful; you have the sum of two independent exponentials in there, which precludes the use of things like the Lambert function...

Comment: Yes, it **is** quite horrible. It is not possible in terms of elementary functions. Numerical procedures are always available. And, at least for limited ranges for the parameters, there may be good approximate *formulas*.